# Angular Material v15 Dark/Light Theme

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

Trying to set dark theme in Angular Material v15

- **theme.scss**:

```js
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

@import 'bluegrey-palette';

$light-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $primary,
    accent: $accent,
    warn: $warn
  )
));

$dark-theme: mat.define-dark-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $primary,
    accent: $accent,
    warn: $warn
  ),
  // typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
  // density: 0
));

@include mat.core-color($light-theme);
@include mat.button-color($light-theme);
//@include mat.all-component-themes($light-theme);

.darkMode {
  @include mat.core-theme($dark-theme);
  @include mat.button-theme($dark-theme);
  @include mat.all-component-colors($dark-theme);
}
```

- _**bluegrey-palette.scss**:

```css
$primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$blue-grey-palette);
$accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$blue-grey-palette);
$warn: mat.define-palette(mat.$blue-grey-palette);
```

It works fine inside a `mat-sidenav-container`, but inside another modules the background remains white and typography remains black.

I tryed this but is not working:

- **index.html**:

  ```html
  <body class="mat-app-background">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
  ```

I made this based on documentation: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#application-background-color

Answer (score 3):

### Static Dark Theme

Adding your *darkMode* class selector to the body tag in *index.html* will get it to work immediately:

```
<body class="mat-app-background darkMode">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

---

### Dynamic dark Theme

If you want to toggle dark and light mode, you will need to create a service and tie the `toggleDarkTheme()` to a button somewhere:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

export class StyleManager {
  isDark = false;

  static readonly darkStyleName = 'darkMode';

  constructor() {}

  public toggleDarkTheme() {
    if (this.isDark) {
      document.body.classList.remove(StyleManager.darkStyleName); // Remove darkMode
      this.isDark = false;
    } else {
      document.body.classList.add(StyleManager.darkStyleName); // Add darkMode
      this.isDark = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you have solved this, am facing the same problem I want to use one primary color for dark and light mode but from the way am setting it up i will have to duplicate the color for both modes here is my setup in-case someone has a better method.

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use 'sass:map';

@include mat.core();

$dark-theme: mat.define-dark-theme((
    color: (primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette), accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$blue-grey-palette)),
    density: -2,
    typography: mat.define-typography-config()
));
$light-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
    color: (primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette), accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$blue-grey-palette))
));

@include mat.all-component-themes($light-theme);
.dark {
  @include mat.all-component-colors($dark-theme);
}
```